# How do I get the row number corresponding to each min and max in the table below

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table with the schema shown below
[image]

For each id, i want the n1 corresponding to max(h) and n2 corresponding to min(l) where n1 and n2 are row numbers

```
Expected output
id    n1    n2
1      3    10
and similar for each id
```

If the max or min value repeats more than once only the first one is considered
I tried

```
select n1, max(h), n2, min(l) from t group by id
```

It gives me an error

```
ERROR:  column "n1" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Help is super appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT t.id,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t.h = sub.h1 THEN n1 END) AS n1,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t.l = sub.l1 THEN n2 END) AS n2
FROM tab_name t
JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(h) AS h1, MIN(l) AS l1
      FROM tab_name
      GROUP BY id) sub
  ON t.id = sub.id
 AND (t.h = sub.h1 OR t.l = sub.l1)
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! testing now, i am assuming this is not possible without joins, like doesnt select distinct on(n1, max(h)) or something work

Comment: @PirateApp I think it could be rewritten a bit easier using windowed function. If you post http://dbfiddle.uk data as sql script (images are very bad) I could check what can be done

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
SELECT id, 
       min(h) as min_h,
       max(h) as max_h,
       max( case when low_rn = 1 then n1 end) as n1_for_min,
       min( case when high_rn = 1 then n1 end) as n1_for_max
FROM (
  SELECT *,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by h) as low_rn,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by h desc) as high_rn
  FROM mytable
) x 
WHERE 1 IN (low_rn, high_rn)
GROUP BY id
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=35fcb41891a8a446bcb55f0a6fd0a774

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has the very convenient `first_value()` function which does what you want . . . almost.  The only inconvenience is that it is a window function, not an analytic function.  That can be resolved using `select distinct`:

```
select distinct id,
       first_value(n1) over (partition by id order by h desc) as n1_at_max_h,
       first_value(n2) over (partition by id order by l desc) as n2_at_max_l
from t;
```

This is probably the simplest method for solving this problem.

If you prefer aggregation, you can use:

```
select id,
       ( array_agg(n1 order by h desc) )[1] as n1_at_max_h,
       ( array_agg(n2 order by l desc) )[1] as n2_at_max_l
from t
group by id;
```